# Unable to add SKSpriteNode to scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm unable to add a SKSpriteNode to a scene in Spritekit with the folling code:

```
 func addScoreNode(){
    scoreNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100,100))
    scoreNode!.position = CGPointMake(50, 450)
    addChild(scoreNode!)
}
```

When I create the node with a texture, it gets added to the screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is and isn't working exactly, it isn't really clear currently.

Comment: The scoreNode isn't being displayed on the screen. If it is, it is invisible. The issue is the first line, scoreNode = SKSpriteNode(color...size). Its declared like  "var scoreNode: SKSpriteNode!" up top.

Comment: Is addScoreLabel() actually run? Is the scoreNode actually on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you are just trying to display text which would be a SKLabelNode or if you are trying to apply a picture to the node But try this at the top of your scene under the class Gamescene : SKScene add

```
var scoreNode = SKSpriteNode()
```

And then instead of the func addScoreNode() put this in the didMoveToView

```
scoreNode.color = UIColor.blueColor()
scoreNode.size = CGSizeMake(100,100)
scoreNode.position = CGPointMake(50, 450)
scoreNode.zPosition = 5 //this brings it to the front of the screen if there are multiple things at this position
```

and either in the didMoveToView or where ever you want it to be called and added to screen

```
self.addChild(scoreNode)
```